# In python, how to make a function accept lower and upper case letters as the same?

Tags: python, string, set, iteration

While I do realise the title is bad and that the solution seem straight foward, bear with me... My function should return the number of occurences a single letter apears in a given string. My function does that, but only if the leters are in the same case (uppeer/lower)... e.g.  str = "aaccbb" should have the output 3 (and it does), but str = "aAbbcc" should have the same output, but it does not and I have tried I think everything I could find on the internet and nothing works. Please help.

```
def occ(txt):
    b=[] 
    for i in set(txt):

        if txt.count(i) > 1:
            b.append(i) 
    return len(b) 

a = "aabbcc" 
print(occ(a))
```

Comment: Lower-case the string before working on it…?!

Comment: So you only want to count characters that occur twice or more?

Comment: Does not work. I need to do it inside the function.

Comment: @lignum: you can do that inside the function.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem any number of times, e. g. "aaa" = 1, "aaaaabbcccccc" =3

Comment: @lignum: but then why you write `count(i) > 1`?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem please, could you show in an example. I feel really stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The description of your function and the implementation seems to contradict each other. The function seems to suggests you want to coun the characters that occur multiple times, whereas the description indicates you want to count the number of different characters.

Regardless what the exact problem is, you can [**`str.casefold`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) your string. So for characters that occur twice or more:

```
from collections import Counter

def occ(txt):
    return sum(d > 1 for d in Counter(txt.casefold()).values())
```

or for all characters:

```
def occ(txt):
    return len(set(txt.casefold()))
```

> A note on lowercase: actually not all characters have a lowercase/uppercase equivalent. Take for example the [*Eszett ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eszett) in German. So converting to lowercase is usually not sufficient to match all cultures.